# Динамический вывод на экран информации в виде отдельного объекта c дальнейшей возможностью внесения изменений

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Передо мной стоит задача проектирования web приложения. Как лучше реализовать вывод на экран отдельных блоков динамически генерирующих информацию с сервера? backend на PHP. Сервер Apache. База данных MySQL.[image: образец]

Лучше создать Класс и добавлять экземпляры. Или есть возможность реализации лучше.
Сложность заключается в создании возможности добавления и редактирования данных картинок и свойств. У меня нет понимания как лучше это сделать. Прошу помочь в данном вопросе.

Comment: Ето полное описание? Что должно быть в блоках? Если блоки однотипные по содержимому, и в зависимости от функционала по можна обойтись.

Comment: Структура блоков одинаковая, разные значения свойств и картинки. Будет так же возможность редактирования или удаления блока контент менеджером, а так же добавление новых. Визуализацию не рассматриваю. нужны подсказки в организации взаимосвязи базы данных и скриптом наполнения.

Answer (score 0):

1. Объектно-ориентированное программирование (ООП). При таком подходе нужно хорошо знать ООП, зачем оно используется и как правильно его готовить.
2. Функциональное программирование (ФП). Этот подход легче для понимания.

Получение и вывод данных практически один и тот же. Дело тут в самих объектах (в ФП тоже можно использовать объекты, но они отличаются от ООП подходом к их получению).

Например (ФП), Вы запросом получаете массив объектов и просто в цикле выводите их. В ООП нужно хорошо разбираться, чтобы не нагородить лишнего.

Comment: Смотрите. Будет большая база контента. свойства в виде характеристик (полей) будут одинаковыми, значения только разные. Вот я и думаю как это лучше реализовать. Сделать многомерный массив, где ключи будут названиями блоков, а значения массивов с наполнением характеристик.Пример: $object_block = array ('home_1' => array('hight' =>'10', 'width=>20'), 'home_2'=> array('hight' =>'10', 'width=>20'));. Или лучше для каждого свойства создать свой массив и обращаться через индекс. $home_hight = array('10', '20', '25',); $home_width = array('100', '200', '250',);

Comment: По кол-ву потребляемой памяти сервера при каждом подходе не могу Вам сказать, т.к. нужно экспериментировать. Но, ИМХО, лучше хранить данные в больших объектах ($object_block), но не старайтесь при этом засунуть вообще ВСЕ данные в один объект.